# tsconfig.tsbuildinfo not being respected

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I am committing tsconfig.tsbuildinfo file in GitHub so that we can optimize ts check on CI build, however, it is not working as expected, in fact, it is taking more time on CI and other machines.
However, if I run ts: check command twice on CI machines, the second build is extremely fast.

tsconfig.json

```html
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react",
    "noEmit": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "paths": {
      "api": ["app/api/index"],
      "modules/*": ["app/modules/*"],
      "lib/*": ["app/lib/*"],
      "tests/*": ["tests/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["**/app/*", "**/tests/*", "**/@types/*"],
  "exclude": [
    "**/node_modules/*",
    "**/internals/*",
    "**/server/*",
    "**/public/*",
    "**/ci_scripts/*",
    "**/testOutput/*",
    "**/build/*",
    "**/app/**/__tests__/*"
  ]
}
```

command in the package.json:
"ts:check": "tsc --project ./tsconfig.json"

command that we run on pipeline: npm run ts:check

Note: TS version is exactly the same for the machine where tsconfig.tsbuildinfo is originally generated and the CI machine

What could be the possible reasons?

Typescript : 4.9.3

Actual behavior
TS check not respecting tsconfig.tsbuildinfo

Expected behavior
TS check should re-use tsconfig.tsbuildinfo and execute check faster

Comment: What is your command in the pipeline and package.json?

Comment: @BrunoMarotta command in package.json is -

"ts:check": "tsc --project ./tsconfig.json",
on pipeline, we run npm run ts:check

Comment: Shouldn't the file be simply named .tsbuildinfo? If not did you try to explicitely setting the filename in the tsconfig? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html

Comment: I have tried setting the name for build info file explicitly but it did not work